# Null check for mapping an array in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

`{data?.map((item, index) =>`

How does the above line of code check for an empty array before mapping? I am not seeing any references for such. Any body please explain?

what does `data?` do?

Reference here: https://dev.to/madara/fetching-data-with-react-hooks-and-fetch-api-beginners-guide-2ick

Comment: It doesn't check for an empty array. If the array is empty the `.map()` method will just return an empty array in return, and the callback function won't be invoked. The `data?` checks that data isn't nullish (undefined / null) before calling .map() on it

Comment: @NickParsons data?.map - a question mark before .map does that?

Comment: The `data?` is [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining), if `data` is null/undefined, the `.map()` method isn't called at all, and your `data?.map()` evaluates to `undefined`. If data is empty, then `.map()` still gets called, but it just returns an empty array (and the callback doesn't get executed).

Comment: This is optional chaining. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining

Answer (score 1):

This is a **condition**, it check if the data exists befor map to avoid returning the error message *"data is null"* or *"data is undefined"*.

```
data?.map((item, index) => { ... })
```

is the same as

```
data 
? data.map((item, index) => { ... }) 
: null
```

and the same as

```
if (data) 
data.map((item, index) => { ... })
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding ternary operator after data (data?) would check first that the data has a value and is not null or undefined, so it can not throw error in that case. It's a short hand for:

> data ? data.map((item, index) => {}) : null

If the data has a value, it would execute map on it.